# holding key breaks java swing form

Tags: java, macos, swing, key-events

I am working on a basic Java Swing UI application, which seems to be working correctly, except for an issue I've noticed when using the form I created.

The problem is when I am typing in the text boxes, holding down a key seems to break the form--ie, after taking this action, the text boxes no longer seem to accept any input.  I find it hard to believe this is a released issue with Java Swing components, but I also can't see how it would be related to my code.  Has anyone seen a similar issue before?  I am using OS x with Intellij IDEA if that is relevant.

My form is defined thusly:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginDialogMcve extends JFrame {

  protected JTextField stringEntry, dateEntry;

  public LoginDialogMcve() {
    super("Create Textbox");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    this.stringEntry = new JTextField(5);
    add(this.stringEntry);

    this.dateEntry = new JTextField(5);
    add(this.dateEntry);

  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    LoginDialogMcve me = new LoginDialogMcve();
    me.pack();
    me.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    me.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Edit: Thanks for the feedback, this is quite possibly not a Java problem.  Could have something to do with OSx... Uploaded simpler example with mcve

Comment: Does the above code, with apparently much code removed, adequately reproduce your problem? Is it sufficient alone to demonstrate your issue for us? And why do you put a value in the ActionMap without putting the same value in the InputMap?

Comment: Yes, the problem is reproducible as far as I can tell with any swing text box.  In particular, it happens before actionPerformed is called, which is why I expect that method to be irrelevant.

I didn't think I would need an inputMap since the only input I will trigger actions from is clicking the validate button.  Does this make sense?  If not what would I use InputMap for?

Comment: OK, after trying to test your code myself, including changing the name of the class in the main method -- I am **not** able to reproduce your problem, meaning that your code is currently not sufficient. Recommending that this question be placed on hold until a valid [mcve] is posted.

Comment: I am able to reproduce with this exact code.  You are able to hold down a letter key, and observe the input, eg

dddddddddddd?


for me it stops immediately, and I can no longer use the form.

Comment: I tried that with my MCVE, but note that most of us do not have MIG layout. I will post my MCVE below as a community wiki so you can test it for yourself.

Comment: Excellent, I'd just like to get it working.  Thank you, suppose it could be an issue specific to MIG layout.

Comment: Seems to be working with MigLayout....your issue may not even be related to Java.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code, I get several compiler errors: `loginDialog.java:8: error: package net.miginfocom.swing does not exist
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
` and `loginDialog.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    CreateTextbox me = new CreateTextbox();`. Please edit your code so that it exactly reproduces the problem you are asking about. If you are using a third-party library, also supply a link to it so that we can install it.

Comment: Also, you should create some code that is as simple as possible. If the problem is really with `JTextField`, then that is all you need. There is no reason to use `MigLayout`, `JLabel`, `JButton`, or `MyAction`.

Comment: Thanks, I've uploaded simpler code that still reproduces the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

My MCVE that works fine. Test it yourself to see.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
// import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginDialogMcve extends JFrame {

    protected JTextField stringEntry, dateEntry;
    protected JLabel stringEntryLabel, dateEntryLabel;
    protected JButton print;
    protected Action validateAction;

    public LoginDialogMcve() {
        super("Create Textbox");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        // setLayout(new MigLayout("ins 10, gap 5",
        // "[][grow]",
        // "[][][]"));

        this.stringEntryLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        add(this.stringEntryLabel);

        this.stringEntry = new JTextField(5);
        add(this.stringEntry);

        this.dateEntryLabel = new JLabel("Date:");
        add(this.dateEntryLabel);

        this.dateEntry = new JTextField(5);
        add(this.dateEntry);

        this.validateAction = new MyAction();

        this.print = new JButton(this.validateAction);
        add(this.print);

        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("validate", this.validateAction);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        LoginDialogMcve me = new LoginDialogMcve();
        me.pack();
        me.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        me.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

        public MyAction() {
            super("Validate");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // lots of irrelevant code
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I get the same issue with that code.  What OS/Swing jars do you use?